# Parse Cloud Code: How to get all posts and check if user liked each post

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Sorry about my english.

I have using Parse Cloud Code With JS Parse SDK.

So, I have three tables:

- User

> +----------+----------+----------+-------|
>
> | objectId | username | password | email |
>
> +----------+----------+----------+-------+

- Post

> +----------+---------+--------------+
>
> | objectId | content | created_user |
>
> +----------+---------+--------------+

***created_user*** is the pointer to User table

- Like

> +----------+--------------+--------------+
>
> | objectId | created_user | created_post |
>
> +----------+--------------+--------------+

***created_user*** is the pointer to User table.

***created_post*** is the pointer to Post table

**Like** is the table which contains an post's id and id of user who liked this post

Now, I have an issue that how to **retrieve all the post and check the user liked it or not.**

I have created a **request** from client which contains the **objectId of user.**

Thank you so much. I hope to be hearing the responses soon.

Comment: The odds of getting a response go up immensely if you include code that others can run. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what programming language are you using, and which database? better give the tables structure (or at least the name plus all the fields names) in a tabular form, not described in text. don't write stuff like please, thank you or sorry, just stick to the actual problem (this are site rules, meant to make reading a question/answer faster). you also need to first try yourself, and then show us your code, and explain what specifically does not work with your code.